# get Double back from core data into text field

Tags: swift, string, core-data, double

I am trying to put numbers into core data and then retrieve them back. I can already this with strings and it all works fine but trying to do it with doubles it seems to store them but not retrieve them. Below is my code. I hope someone can help, Thank you in advance if you can.

To retrive...

```
    func getTranscriptions18CW () {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()
    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults18CW = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        if indexPageSum == 18 {
            for trans in searchResults18CW as [NSManagedObject] {
                let result = trans.value(forKey: "cWeight")
                if result != nil {

                    CWeight.text = result! as? String
                }
            }
        }
    }catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

then to Save.

```
   func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    _ = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return DataController().managedObjectContext
}


func storeTranscription18CW (pageText: Double, textFileUrlString: String) {


    let context = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: context)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    // set the entity values
    if indexPageSum == 18 {
        transc.setValue(pageText, forKey: "cWeight")
    }
    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

then another part to save.

```
 if indexPageSum == 18 {
                            let CWConvert = Double(CWeight.text!)
                            storeTranscription18CW(pageText: (CWConvert)!, textFileUrlString: "cWeight")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
result! as? String
```

basically means "if `result` is of type `String` then return it, otherwise return `nil`". This works fine for `String`s stored in the DB, but assigns `nil` to `CWeight.text` for anything else.

You want something like the following:

```
if let result = trans.value(forKey: "cWeight") {
    if let str = result as? String {
        CWeight.text = str
    }
    else {
        CWeight.text = "\(result)"
    }
}
```

This will work for the most common data types. The expression `"\(result)"` uses string interpolation to convert the value stored in `result` to an appropriate string.

You probably also want to look into generating `NSManagedObject` subclasses to make this easier to handle.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, this worked for the first one that i want to save but then when i change them all (8) to the same thing with different names it only saves the last one as the number the rest it makes 0 i think its to do with this part....if indexPageSum == 18 {
                                
   var CWConvert = Double(CWeight.text!)
   storeTranscription18CW(pageText: (CWConvert)!, textFileUrlString: "cWeight")
                                    
         CWConvert = Double(TWeight.text!)
         storeTranscription18TW(pageText: (CWConvert)!, textFileUrlString: "tWeight")

Comment: Can you post the full code somewhere accessible? Or share it privately? It seems like there may be other things to tackle here.